# Return Row Number based on 2 columns matching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to represent the following in a google sheets formula. - Column G, Row Number
[image]

I can do this using a vlookup and arrayFormula - e.g arrayFormula(vlookup(e2&" "f2,{A&" "&B,C},2))

However this returns the cell value. I've also tried using the MATCH function, but it only accepts 1 column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (even an appscript solution)

Answer (score 1):

- `A,B,C` are invalid ranges. Use `A:A`, `B:B`...
- Use MATCH:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(e2&" "f2,{A:A&" "&B:B,C:C},0))
  ```